# Drupal 500 error

Tags: drupal-8, internal-server-error

I have an internal server error on my drupal site only when I log in, when logged out everything is fine.

I was having problems with the default image-styles, they would not work (no thumbnail preview) so I created a new style (thumbnail2), deleted the default thumbnail style and replaced it with thumbnail2 style.

Any ideas how I recover from this?

So 2 problems:

1. get access to admin again
2. get default images styles to work

*edit*
Server log:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "view.media.media_page_list" does not exist."
```

*edit* from comments

So here is the code chunk it is refering to in drupal:

```
public function getRouteByName($name) { 
    $routes = $this->getRoutesByNames(array($name)); 
    if (empty($routes)) { 
        throw new RouteNotFoundException(sprintf('Route "%s" does not exist.', $name)); 
    } 
    return reset($routes); 
}
```

Comment: what do your server logs say?

Comment: Ihave this:  
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException: "Route "view.media.media_page_list" does not exist." at /var/www/.../core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php line 187

Comment: So here is the code chunk it is refering to in drupal:

  public function getRouteByName($name) {
    $routes = $this->getRoutesByNames(array($name));
    if (empty($routes)) {
      throw new RouteNotFoundException(sprintf('Route "%s" does not exist.', $name));
    }

    return reset($routes);
  }

Comment: er... you dont have the route `view.media.media_page_list` defined possibly? if thats coming from a module, delete/rename the module folder and try to reload.

Comment: I renamed modules media_entity and media_entity_image (putting an x prefix) restarted apache, same result following login

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix this by re-enabling the media (media_page_list) view by running

```
drush ven media
```

via drush.
Long variation: drush views:enable ven

The view was simply disabled after replacing drupal/media by media in 8.3.x core, which caused the problems.